# Auto-mounting several Windows shared-folders doesn't always work

Tags: networking, fstab, automount, shared-folders, cifs

I've got a problem with network shared-folders configuration in fstab:

I'm on Ubuntu 18.04.

I've modified my `/etc/fstab`, adding these lines:

```
//192.168.x.x/Common_space /media/common_space cifs _netdev,vers=1.0,sec=ntlm,credentials=/root/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,nounix,rw,noserverino,uid=1000   0   0
//192.168.x.x/Second_folder /media/second_forlder cifs _netdev,vers=1.0,sec=ntlm,credentials=/root/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,nounix,rw,noserverino,uid=1000    0   0
//192.168.x.x/Third /media/third cifs _netdev,vers=1.0,sec=ntlm,credentials=/root/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,nounix,rw,noserverino,uid=1000 0   0
//192.168.x.x/fourth /media/fourth cifs _netdev,vers=1.0,sec=ntlm,credentials=/root/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,nounix,rw,noserverino,uid=1000   0   0
```

(this configuration worked on the same network, with an Ubuntu 14.04. I've just added `vers=1.0,sec=ntlm`)

If I type `sudo mount -a` in a terminal, all my distant disks are mounted, without a problem.

BUT

When I boot my computer, 0 or 1 disk is mounted (not always the same). If I click on one of the others, I've got the error message:

> mount /media/second_folder : operation permitted for root only.

Nota: my `/media/…` folders are my property
(I've made `sudo chown` me /media/common_space, etc.)

Why could this work manually, but not with fstab?

And why would a shared-folder work (it's not always the same), but not the others?

Comment: Add `x-systemd.after=network-online.target` to the options in `/etc/fstab`. I've heard it can work if `_netdev` is not enough. See [this discussion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/349264/fstab-mount-wait-for-network).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I've tried to add this option, but Ubuntu didn't boot anymore. After I entered my password, screen was blank (there was only the mouse pointer).  I've removed the options in a terminal with vi, and I retrieved my session. I'll try one more time.

Comment: Yes, it works... almost! Now, I can have 4 to 6 shared folders connected, out of 8.  For the rest of the shared-folders, I've got another error message : "error 13 (Permission denied) opening credential file / root/.smbcredentials."  But it may not be the problem : 4 connections have access to this file, and they aren't the same from one boot to another.